# What does { content: [Circular] } mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

My code was:

```
var chineseBox = {};
chineseBox.content = chineseBox;
```

and it returned:

```
{ content: [Circular] }
```

What does that mean?

Comment: This is not part of javascript (Ecmascript) - the chineseBox return a JSON object that specified that the content is Circular (whatever that means to the chineseBox)

Comment: It returned that how? Something is missing here.

Comment: The second line of code will evaluate to the rvalue, which is `chineseBox`. Just the same way `chineseBox.content = 5` would evaluate to `5`.

Comment: Interesting aside: there's a [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-global) to add a property to the JavaScript global object which has the key "global" (so you'd access it with `<global object name here>.global`), and which returns the global object (a circular reference). Then, you'd be able to simply call `global` anywhere, and because every property of the JS global object is accessible by just its property name alone, asking for `global` would always return the global object no matter what the global object was actually named ('window', 'process', 'whatever' etc)

Comment: @chelsea how on earth did you get the chelsea twitter handle :D I am impressed.

Answer (score 23):

Your object contains a [circular reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference#In_computer_programming). If you tried to print (or serialize) this object you would end up in an infinite loop

```
{content: {content: {content ...
```

Instead, your system was smart enough to notice the circularity and protect itself against it.

Comment: Thank you! and @numbers1311407 this is literally what my terminal looked like: http://d.pr/nE8a

Comment: Cool, that would be Node.js; which uses the V8 engine.

Answer (score 9):

It means that you have defined a circular reference. In other words, a variable that references itself.

Put another way, `chineseBox` is equal to `chineseBox.content` is equal to `chineseBox.content.content` is equal to `chineseBox.content.content.content` is equal to `chineseBox.content.content.content.content` is equal to `chineseBox.content.content.content.content.content` is equal to `chineseBox.content.content.content.content.content.content` is equal to `chineseBox.content.content.content.content.content.content.content` is equal to `chineseBox.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content` is equal to `chineseBox.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content` is equal to `chineseBox.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content` is equal to `chineseBox.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content` is equal to `chineseBox.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content` is equal to `chineseBox.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content.content` ... and so on ad infinitum.

Since such a circular reference quite clearly cannot be expressed in any finite manner, the result of `[Circular]` is shown. Other languages have their own phrase for the term, such as PHP which displays `*RECURSION*`. There's nothing particularly world-ending about circular references, just that they're pretty useless most of the time.

A back-and-forth reference, such as `a.thing = b; b.thing = a;` can be useful, though, for use in linked lists or other chains that you need to be able to navigate backwards as well as forwards - again, you can write `a.thing.thing.thing.thing.thing.thing` as much as you want.

Answer (score 3):

Thats because chineseBox.content has a reference to chineseBox which is the same Object.
A Circular reference...