# Trouble understanding basic object workings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I'm learning JavaScript and there's an example in the book I'm using that I didn't understand.
It's like this:

```
var chineseBox = {};
chineseBox.content = chineseBox;
```

Then the book lists two expressions and their values. First, `"content' in chineseBox;` that returns `true`. Then, the one I don't get, `"content" in chineseBox.content` which also returns `true`.
I think it'd be more natural if the second expression evaluated to `false`, pointing to the empty `chineseBox` object defined earlier.
Is there a reason to work like this? What are the practical implications of this feature?
And how do I explore deeper levels of the object? Is `chineseBox.content.content` right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does { content: \[Circular\] } mean in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923959/what-does-content-circular-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: @Esailija: Wouldn't call that a dupe. It's the same code but a differently worded question.

Comment: @Matt answering the dupe question means you have to answer this question as well... even if they're differently worded. See the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think it'd be more natural if the second expression evaluated to `false`, pointing to the empty `chineseBox` object defined earlier.

It's not empty anymore. As of `chineseBox.content = chineseBox`, it now has a property.

When you assign object references to things (variables, properties, etc.), the value stored is a *reference* to the object, not a *copy* of it. So both `chineseBox` (the variable) and `chineseBox.content` (the property) point to the **same** object, which has a property called `content`.

Let's throw some ASCII art at this:

```
var chineseBox = {};
```

That gives us:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| chineseBox (variable) |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| value                 |−−−−−−−−−>|    (object)   |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                   |               |
                                   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Now we do

```
chineseBox.content = chineseBox;
```

...and we have:

```
                                            /−−−−−−−−−−−\
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                   |           |
| chineseBox (variable) |                   v           |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |
| value                 |−−−−−−−−−>|    (object)   |    |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |
                                   |  content      |−−−−/
                                   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

There's just one object. There are two references pointing to it.

Comment: The drawings really helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`chineseBox.content` is a reference to `chineseBox`; and it's important that it's a reference, as it means any future changes to `chineseBox` are **also** visible in the `chineseBox.content` reference.

When you set `chineseBox.content` to `chineseBox`, the `chineseBox` object is indeed empty; however because `chineseBox` is a reference, as *soon* as you set the `content` attribute, it updates to reflect that.

See `chineseBox.content === chineseBox // true`

Answer (score 0):

`chineseBox.content = chineseBox;` means that `chinesesBox.content` **points back to** `chineseBox`. So yes, you can go `chineseBox.content.content.content` etc, because each time you're going back to the root element

Answer (score 0):

`'content' in chineBox.content` evaluates to **true** since  `content` points to the **original**  `chineseBox` object (chineseBox.content --> chineseBox).

`chineseBox.content.content`,  `chineseBox.content.content....content` are all valid, because you are referring to the same object.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel: primitive in the sense of **original**.