# Why does my algorithm say [circular]? (NodeJS simple algorithm)

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, object, circular-dependency

```
var swapPairs = function(head) {
    if (head == null || head.next == null) {
        return; 
    }
    let oldHead = head;
    let nextHead = head.next;
    oldHead.next = swapPairs(nextHead.next);
    head.next = oldHead;
    return head;
};

console.log(swapPairs(list.head));
```

Any  clue why Node JS responds with each head but responds with a next value of "[circular]"?

For example: 
{ value: 16, next: [Circular] }

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923959/what-does-content-circular-mean-in-javascript

Comment: Because it is circular. You are setting `head.next` to `head` at this line: `head.next = oldHead`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does { content: \[Circular\] } mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923959/what-does-content-circular-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's circular - it's infinitely nested:

```
value: 16,
next: {
    next: {
        next: {...}
    }
}
```