# Getting a "Circular" added to my array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, circular-dependency

In the process of learning Javascript.
I have written a code which goes through an array and adds them to `res` array. It will also go through the nested arrays and add them element by element to `res`. I have used recursion for this. But after each nested array finishes I am getting a `Circular` added to `res`. Unable to find where the problem is.

```
var res = ["oldarray"];

function findthis(xar){
  for(let n=0; n<xar.length; n++) {
    if(xar[n] instanceof Array) {
      res.push(findthis(xar[n]));
    } else {
      res.push(xar[n]);
    }
  }
  return res;
}

var d = ["z", 9, 2, ["r", "r", ["X","X","X","X"], "r"], "f", "x"];

console.log(findthis(d));
```

output this gives. when it should be an array without the added [Circular]

```
['oldarray', 'z', 9, 2, 'r', 'r', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', [Circular], 'r', [Circular], 'f', 'x']
```

Comment: What is the output supposed to look like?

Comment: same as the output but without the [Circular] added.

Comment: then change `res.push(findthis(xar[n]));` to `findthis(xar[n]);` That's where you push the circular references.

Comment: Does this answer on SO help you define what [Circular] means, and why its getting printed for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923959/what-does-content-circular-mean-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[Circular]` is printed out when you try to print an array or an object that contains a reference to itself. Here, you're getting it because you push the result of `findthis` (which is `res`) into `res` itself. To fix this, just remove the call to `push` in that case:

```js
function findthis(xar){
  for(let n=0; n<xar.length; n++) {
    if(xar[n] instanceof Array) {
      findthis(xar[n]); // Here! findthis already pushes to res, no need for another push
    } else {
      res.push(xar[n]);
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Nailed it. That makes complete sense now that you point it out.